# Troubleshooting "No Module Found" Error with Capacitor Plug-in and xfcFramework SDK in Main App, works locally but not from repo

Tags: ios, swift, ionic-framework, capacitor, capacitor-plugin

I've encountered a bit of a challenge with a particular scenario, and I could use some assistance. Here's the situation: I'm in the process of developing a custom Capacitor plug-in, which utilizes the Citizen printer SDK (xfcframework). Locally, I can successfully compile my main Capacitor app with the plug-in using Xcode. However, when I retrieve the same plug-in from my online repository (Bitbucket) and rebuild the main app, I encounter an error stating "no module found." I'm uncertain about what I might be overlooking or where my path could be incorrect when using a Capacitor plug-in sourced from a repository like Bitbucket.

Please note the error is coming from the swift class found in the development pod section at the plug in level.

`npm install xxxxxx`

my pod spec on my capacitor plug in has the following setup

```
  s.source_files = 'ios/Plugin/**/*.{swift,h,m,c,cc,mm,cpp}'
  s.ios.deployment_target  = '13.0'
  s.dependency 'Capacitor'
  s.ios.vendored_frameworks = './ios/framework/CSJPOSLibSwift.xcframework'
  s.swift_version = '5.1'
```

The SDK xfcFramework does not have a any spec file so I can't install it via cocapod
the struct of the folder is like this

the structure of my sdk folder is like this

```
CSJPOSLibSwift.xcframework
  - info.plist
  - ios-arm64_armv7_armv7s
     - Headers
     - info.plist
     - Modules
  - ios-arm64_i386_x86_64-simulator
  -
```

I added my framework to the plug in project to the following directory

```
iOS
 - Frameworks
    - CSJPOSLibSwift.xcframework
```